# NodeMailer- Sending email in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I am newbie to nodejs and learning by implementing some examples.I am trying to send an email using nodemailer using below code:

```
    var smtpConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        pass: 'xxx@a'
    }
  };

   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

   // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
   var mailOptions = {
      from: '"Fred Foo ?" <xxx@gmail.com>', // sender address
      to: 'xxx@gmail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
      text: 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
      html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
   };

   // send mail with defined transport object
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if(error){
        return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
       });
     }
```

I am getting following error when i run:

[image]

Can anyone let me know where am i doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

Verified connection configuration using below code:

```
// verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
   if (error) {
        console.log(error);
   } else {
        console.log('Server is ready to take our messages');
   }
});
```

The verification returns error- `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

Checked these-

- Not a firewall issue, as it was disabled
- Enabled-  Access for less secure apps

Thanks,
WH

Comment: @JohannesMerz- Its not firewall issue in my case as mentioned in that post

Comment: @nhouser9, Andre Figueiredo, Vini.g.fer, Coatless, Aditya Vyas-Lakhan - Please , can someone provide me what should be the resolution for this issue if this is marked as duplicate, as i mentioned in my earlier comment that firewall couldn't be an issue since its disabled already.